# lsmod gives error: "could not get list of modules" on Debian running on WSL

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, sysctl, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I run `lsmod` or `sudo lsmod`, I get an error that says:

```
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1655 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
```

I searched on a lot of forums but am unable to find a solution for this. I'm running Debian on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I was recently also trying to edit the `sysctl.conf` file for the purpose of disabling *ipv6*. I had added the following lines:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And when I tried `sudo sysctl -p`, it returned this error:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/disable_ipv6: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if the above 2 errors are connected. I was trying to run Linux shell on Windows. Any solution to the problem?

Comment: Debian on WSL is not exactly the same thing...I am not much surprised about the IPv6 tidbit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both cases, you’re trying to interact with the kernel. Any Linux environment running on WSL isn’t running a Linux kernel, it’s running on the Windows kernel; so anything tied to the Linux kernel (including modules and system controls) won’t work.

In the IPv6 case, you need to configure the network using Windows’ tools.

Comment: Is there any work around to this? And could there be instances where I would need to probably interact with the kernel in order to perform some important task? Is there a workaround in that case?

Comment: The workaround is to run a full Linux environment, *e.g.* in a VM. There are some things which you can only do with a Linux kernel, just as there are others you can only do with Windows. You need to use the appropriate tool for your requirements; WSL gives you a Linux user-space on Windows, but it isn’t Linux.

Comment: WSL gives you a Linux user-space on Windows, but it isn’t Linux.@StephenKitt Good

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly related to WSL, but you can see this error if your kernel was compiled without loadable module support.

Without module support, `/proc/modules` doesn't exist, which is what `lsmod` relies on for most of its information.

If you are compiling your own kernel, the option to look for is CONFIG_MODULES.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was trying to do nfs mounts in WSL. You can connect to your drives using windows, then mount them in WSL.

```
sudo mount -t drvfs G: /mnt/g
```

For the full answer where I got this from:
https://superuser.com/questions/1128634/how-to-access-mounted-network-drive-on-windows-linux-subsystem/1261563#1261563